# Как запустить приложение компьютера из JS?

Tags: javascript, windows, google-chrome, протоколы

написал небольшой скрипт, для запуска приложения с компьютера:

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(()=>{
chrome.contextMenus.create({
    id: 'click1',
    title: 'Открыть во Фронпейдж',
    contexts: ['all']
});
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(({menuItemId})=>{
    if(menuItemId === 'click1')
    {
        chrome.tabs.query({active: true}, (tabs) => {
            const tab = tabs[0];
            if (tab) {
                const url = new URL (tab.url);
                const url1 = url.hostname +url.pathname;
                chrome.tabs.create({url:'FrontOpen:'+(tab.url)});
            }
        })
    }
});
```

});

Создал вот такой протокол :

[image: Создал вот такой протокол]

Но, почему-то в приложение, URL приходит вместе с первым параметром, а второй - пустой, если указать в реестре %1 - то приходит вот что "frontopen:[https://www.google.com/"](https://www.google.com/%22) - и , соответственно страница не загружается во ФП, подскажите как разделить параметры?

Comment: Я бы попробовал вместо 'FrontOpen:' использовать 'FrontOpen: ', 'FrontOpen:+' и 'FrontOpen:%20'.

Comment: @ВикторКарев , это я всё перепробовал - не робит, к сожалению (